# @ViewScoped JSF bean getting initialized multiple times

Tags: jsf, view, primefaces, javabeans, instantiation

I'm using **primefaces 4.0** and **Mojarra 2.2.6**

I'm opening a dialog box (modal) from a session scoped bean - in the dialogue I've a `@ViewScoped` bean initialized which retrieves few list of names (strings) from the session map etc.

Problem is that every time I submit by clicking on the save button, new `viewScoped` bean is created which is obviously not the behavior I want. I saw many other questions on the same topic answered and have also tried setting web.xml with:

`<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>`

But it still doesn't work.  I also eliminated almost every tag except an inputfield and the submit button to eliminate any specific tag handler that may be causing it but still can't seem it to pinpoint why it's not working.  Here is my sample `xhtml` page and `viewScope` bean save method:

**session bean code**:

```
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("NAMES", names);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("modal", true);
        map.put("draggable", false);
        map.put("resizable", false);
        map.put("dynamic", true);
        map.put("contentHeight", 500);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("SaveNames.xhtml", map, null );
```

**XHTML**:

    `<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
<h:form id="myform"
<p:inputText id="newFolderName" disabled="#{not mybean.list}" value="#{mybean.newName}" autocomplete="off"></p:inputText>
            <p:commandButton id="saveNewNameButton" type="push" value="Save"
                action="#{mybean.saveNewName}"
                icon="ui-icon-disk" oncomplete="exit()" style="float: right">
            </p:commandButton>
</h:form>`

**view scope bean**:

```
public void saveNewName()
{ //saving logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after whole day of troubleshooting found out really silly reason for this. Posting answer in case someone else may end up having same issue.

I was using the wrong `@ViewScoped` package annotation.  Apparently there are two annotations, `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` and `javax.bean.ViewScoped` -

The correct one to use is `javax.bean.ViewScoped` - however if you are not paying attention in STS/eclipse when it suggest packages in autocomplete that you may end picking up the wrong one which may cause this issue.

Comment: `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped ` is for use with CDI backing beans